# how to change code so it works with itext 7

Tags: itext, itext7

The following code works nicely with iText 5:

```
LEVEL = PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_3A
writer = PdfAWriter.getInstance(document, baos, LEVEL)
```

What is the correct syntax for iText 7?

Where can I find examples and documentation about iText 7?

Comment: Indeed I did, and that remains true for that version, but this requires quite significant changes which are not properly documented ( at the  moment there might be a change-log on the site but not anywhere that I have discovered after over an hour of searching). I received many emails recently encouraging me to vote for the company in a European competition, does it not seem a good idea to share with developers the package changes you have made and how to use the new model as well??

Comment: I see that my up-vote turned the negative score into a neutral 0 score. There's no changelog because iText 7 was rewritten from scratch. A changelog just doesn't make any sense. You're right regarding the documentation: we need more of it. However, we decided to use a lean approach and make iText 7 available the same way iText 0.30 was made available. We could have waited with the release of iText 7 until the documentation was finished, but at heart, we're still open source developers and we went back to our grassroots: let's publish the code so the OS developers can already play with iText 7.

Comment: By the way: every unnecessary question steals time from the writing process. There's a second tutorial in the works: http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks Don't underestimate my own frustration as a writer whenever I have tasks to do that stand in the way of writing. Writing is hard. I'd rather have people sending me constructive criticism (such as reports with typos and errors) than people slowing down the writing process by airing negative criticism.

Answer (score 1):

why so negative? Seems like you want to put extra pressure on me to write documentation. That's kind of frustrating. I think that encouragement works better. Nevertheless, your claim that there's no documentation is wrong.

See [Chapter 7: Creating PDF/UA and PDF/A documents](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-7-creating-pdfua-and-pdfa-documents) of the [iText 7: Jump-Start Tutorial](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial)

You overlooked the [UnitedStates_PDFA_3a](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/examples/chapter-7#1810-c07e03_unitedstates_pdfa_3a.java) example in which we have a CSV file that we convert to a PDF/A-3 document adding that CSV file as attachment.

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, XMPException {
    PdfADocument pdf = new PdfADocument(new PdfWriter(dest),
        PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_3A,
        new PdfOutputIntent("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org",
                "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", new FileInputStream(INTENT)));
    Document document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A4.rotate());
    document.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 20);

    //Setting some required parameters
    pdf.setTagged();
    pdf.getCatalog().setLang(new PdfString("en-US"));
    pdf.getCatalog().setViewerPreferences(
            new PdfViewerPreferences().setDisplayDocTitle(true));
    PdfDocumentInfo info = pdf.getDocumentInfo();
    info.setTitle("iText7 PDF/A-3 example");

    //Add attachment
    PdfDictionary parameters = new PdfDictionary();
    parameters.put(PdfName.ModDate, new PdfDate().getPdfObject());
    PdfFileSpec fileSpec = PdfFileSpec.createEmbeddedFileSpec(
        pdf, Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(DATA)), "united_states.csv",
        "united_states.csv", new PdfName("text/csv"), parameters,
        PdfName.Data, false);
    fileSpec.put(new PdfName("AFRelationship"), new PdfName("Data"));
    pdf.addFileAttachment("united_states.csv", fileSpec);
    PdfArray array = new PdfArray();
    array.add(fileSpec.getPdfObject().getIndirectReference());
    pdf.getCatalog().put(new PdfName("AF"), array);

    //Embed fonts
    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FONT, true);
    PdfFont bold = PdfFontFactory.createFont(BOLD_FONT, true);

    // Create content
    Table table = new Table(new float[]{4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1});
    table.setWidthPercent(100);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(DATA));
    String line = br.readLine();
    process(table, line, bold, true);
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        process(table, line, font, false);
    }
    br.close();
    document.add(table);

    //Close document
    document.close();
}

public void process(Table table, String line, PdfFont font, boolean isHeader) {
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, ";");
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        if (isHeader) {
            table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(tokenizer.nextToken()).setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).setFont(font)));
        } else {
            table.addCell(new Cell().setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(tokenizer.nextToken()).setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).setFont(font)));
        }
    }
}
```